# Find solutions to equation with section wise defined function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, solver

I'm pretty new to MATLAB and trying to reverse a conversion from an altitude to a Reynold's number.
The function altitude -> Reynold's number is defined section wise, because different methods apply, depending on the altitude being higher or lower than a threshold.

The conversion is given by this function:

```matlab
function [Re] = convertAltToRe(h, Ma, L)

%% Constants   
    h_trop = 11000;     % [m] - ISA altitude of tropopause
    rho_0 = 1.225;      % [kg/m^3] - Standard density of air
    T_0 = 288.15;       % [K] - ISA Reference Temperature 
    T_tropo = 216.65;   % [K] - Reference temperature for 11,000m < h < 20,000m
    T_s = 273.15;       % [K] - Standard temperature
    dT = -0.0065;       % [K/m] - Temperature gradient up to 11,000m
    k = 1.4;            % [-] - Isentropic exponent dry air
    R = 287.058;        % [J/(K*kg)] - Specific gas constant dry air
    my_0 = 1.716e-005;  % [Pa*s] - Dynamic viscosity at sealevel
    C = 110.4;          % [K] - Sutherland constant dry air
    g = 9.80665;        % [m/s^2] - Gravitational accerleration
    
%% TAS from speed of sound
    if h < h_trop
        c_s = sqrt((T_0+(dT*h))*k*R);
    else
        c_s = sqrt(T_tropo*k*R); 
    end
    v = Ma * c_s;
    
%% Dynamic viscosity
    beta = my_0*(T_s+C)/(T_s^1.5);
    T = T_0 + dT*h;
    
    if h < h_trop
        my = beta*T^(1.5)/(T+C);
    else
        my = beta*T_tropo^(1.5)/(T_tropo+C);
    end

%% Density
    if h < h_trop
        rho = rho_0*(1+(dT*h/T_0))^(-g/R/dT-1);
    else
        rho = rho_0*(T_tropo/T_0)^(-g/R/dT-1)*exp(-g/R/T_tropo*(h-h_trop));
    end
    
%% Reynold's number
    Re = rho*v*L/my;

end
```

Now I try to find the altitude for a given `Ma`, `L` and `Re`.

My attempt looks like this:

```matlab
Re = 2.693844519000000e+07; 

syms f;
syms x real;
f = convertAltToRe(x, 0.78,4.371623535)  == Re; 

res = vpasolve(f,x,10000);
```

The error message says that the operation `h < h_trop` is not possible, because it is a conversion from a symbolic variable to a locigal value.

Is it possible to solve an equation of this form?

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** There seems to be a zero that can be found with `min`

```
Re = 2.693844519000000e+07;

dh=[0:.01:2e4];
Ma=0.78
L=4.371623535

h=alttore(dh,Ma,L);
h_dB=10*log10(abs(h-Re));

figure
plot(dh,h_dB)
grid on
```

[image]

```
[mval,mind]=min(h_dB)
h0=alttore(dh(mind),Ma,L)
```

h0 =
2.662955072438022e+07

**2.-** Narrowing `dh` window one increases resulting `h0` accuracy

```
dh=[1:.0001:1.2e4];
h=alttore(dh,Ma,L);
h_dB=10*log10(abs(h-Re));
[mval,mind]=min(h_dB)

h0=alttore(dh(mind),Ma,L)
```

h0 =
2.662954575557600e+07